# Identifying unknown structured data formats – what could be class-oriented JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm currently working with a Sophos UTM, pushing the wireless statistics to another platform and trying to digest this data format.
It's clearly structured and looks like class-oriented JSON, but cannot quite figure out what it is or how to convert it to something usable. Any ideas? I thought about just writing a JSON-converter in PHP, but I'm afraid that I might just be missing a puzzle piece.

```
{
      'clients' => {
                     '0c:2c:54:xx:xx:xx' => {
                                              'ap' => '',
                                              'connected_time_sec' => 1720,
                                              'connected_time_str' => '00:28:40',
                                              'hwaddr' => '0c:2c:54:xx:xx:xx',
                                              'ip' => '172.16.28.206',
                                              'last_rxrate_bps' => '1048576',
                                              'last_rxrate_str' => '1024.0 kbit/s',
                                              'last_txrate_bps' => '6815744',
                                              'last_txrate_str' => '6.5 Mbit/s',
                                              'lastseen_str' => '2018-11-04 18:06:37',
                                              'lastseen_ts' => 1541351197,
                                              'mesh_id' => '',
                                              'mesh_mode' => 'none',
                                              'name' => 'HUAWEI_P20_Pro',
                                              'radio_id' => '0',
                                              'signal_per' => '39',
                                              'ssid' => 'ssid',
                                              'vendor' => 'unknown'
                                            },
                     '44:d8:84:xx:xx:xx' => {
                                              'ap' => 'A40001AXX8FXXXX',
                                              'connected_time_sec' => 534992,
                                              'connected_time_str' => '06:04:36:32',
                                              'hwaddr' => '44:d8:84:xx:xx:xx',
                                              'ip' => '172.16.28.149',
                                              'last_rxrate_bps' => '1048576',
                                              'last_rxrate_str' => '1024.0 kbit/s',
                                              'last_txrate_bps' => '60607488',
                                              'last_txrate_str' => '57.8 Mbit/s',
                                              'lastseen_str' => '2018-11-04 20:44:28',
                                              'lastseen_ts' => 1541360668,
                                              'mesh_id' => '',
                                              'mesh_mode' => 'none',
                                              'name' => 'iMac-OBC',
                                              'radio_id' => '0',
                                              'signal_per' => '65',
                                              'ssid' => 'ssid',
                                              'vendor' => 'Apple'
                                            }
                   },
      'connected' => {
                       'A40001AXX8FXXXX' => {
                                              'associated_clients' => [
                                                                        'ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl',
                                                                        '44:d8:84:xx:xx:xx',
                                                                      ],
                                              'bss' => undef,
                                              'id' => 'A40001AXX8FXXXX',
                                              'ip' => '192.168.10.11',
                                              'lan_mac' => '00:1a:8c:xx:xx:xx',
                                              'location' => 'AP30',
                                              'type' => 'AP30',
                                              'wifi_mac' => '00:1a:8c:xx:xx:xx'
                                            },
                       'A4000EASIJDFSDOI' => {
                                              'associated_clients' => [],
                                              'bss' => undef,
                                              'id' => 'A4000EASIJDFSDOI',
                                              'ip' => '192.168.10.12',
                                              'lan_mac' => '00:1a:8c:xx:xx:xx',
                                              'location' => 'AP30',
                                              'type' => 'AP30',
                                              'wifi_mac' => '00:1a:8c:xx:xx:xx'
                                            }
                     },
      'disconnected' => {},
      'lastupdate' => 1541360678
    }
```

Comment: I'd say, [replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) every `=>` by `:` and then use `json_decode` to convert into an object

Comment: Open source clients for this system online seem to indicate that JSON is coming back.  Where are you getting the data you're seeing here?  Is there any way to request JSON instead?

Comment: this is not valid JSON. How exactly did you get this result? From this sample, it's quite close to JSON, so what Nino said is potentially a reasonable solution. But a better solution would be to get some actual JSON from this system in the first place, if you can.

Comment: It's basically a file on a Linux system I'm pushing to my server via FTP. Therefore there doesn't seem to be a way to request another data format for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data has 4 repairs to make on the road to valid json town.

Make the following replacements:

1. `=>` to `:`
2. `'` to `"`
3. remove all trailing `,` that are followed by zero or more whitespace characters then a `]`
4. wrap your `undef` values in double quotes

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XgKMa))

```
$almostjson = <<<ALMOSTJSON
...your input string
ALMOSTJSON;
$json = preg_replace(["~=>~", "~'~", "~,(?=\s*])~", "~:\s+\Kundef~"], [':', '"', '', '"$0"'], $almostjson);
var_export(json_decode($json, true));
```

Calling regex functions on strings that contain key-value relationships is vulnerable to unintended matching.  This "solution" should be considered a "bandaid" until the source of the data can be improved.  This solution may silently fail in the future if the wrong quality of text is in the string.

Comment: Used this. Works as expected. 

Comment: Nice.  ...just remember what I said though...  This thing is just a bandaid.